# Can Spring batch used for data processing or it is only an ETL tool?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to utilize Spring Batch in one of the projects that I have, as there is another project that is based on Spring Batch.

However the more I read the more I realize that Spring batch is nothing like ApacheBeam or MapReduce, it is only used for transferring the **SAME** data from one place to another with some type mapping like varchar -> string.

However, the task in hand requires some processing, not only types mapping and converting but also aggregations and data structure. 
Can Spring batch used for data processing or it is only an ETL tool ?

Answer (score 4):

well, i disagree on this point  that spring batch - is only used for transferring the SAME data from one place to another with some type mapping like varchar -> string.

Worked in 4 years in this technology and have witnessed this framework grow a lot.

Spring batch is well capable of processing data, mapping, required conversion and data aggregations - spring batch can definitely be used for data processing .

being open source technology - you will get lot of material to read about, and the forums like stackoverflow have ton of FAQs around it.

For scaling and paralleling there are various architectures in spring batch, which will help in enhancing your performance.

Further details you can find here

[SPRING_BATCH_SCALING_AND_PARALLELING](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/reference/html/scalability.html)

If you want to monitor your jobs then you cas use - Spring cloud date flow. 
Monitoring can also be done - with AppDynamics.

Referrer this blog  -

[MONITOR_SPRING_BATCH_JOB_WITH_APP_DYNAMICS](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/04/monitoring-spring-batch-with-appdynamics/)

Another advantage of using spring batch is you have lot of standerd predefined reader , processor and writer types - which support sources like file , DB , stream etc..

On top of this - as it is a java based framework you can do all stuff that can be done with java.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is a good one and probably what you are saying is true. But the point is Spring Batch is mainly for ETL, processing can be accomplished but with some extra effort it is not the main point of the framework, is this a valid point ?

Comment: i would say yes , that is a valid point - for processing extra efforts will be needed -  but if you know any good java based framework for processing - then it can be easily integrated with it

Comment: you would be surprised about the batch performance - just check this out demo on InfoQ - https://www.infoq.com/presentations/batch-performance-spring-4-1/?useSponsorshipSuggestions=true

Answer (score 3):

Your below write up is incorrect because its comparing apples to oranges,

> However the more I read the more I realize that Spring batch is
>   nothing like ApacheBeam or MapReduce, it is only used for transferring
>   the SAME data from one place to another with some type mapping like
>   varchar -> string.

Unlike ApacheBeam  or MapReduce, Spring Batch is not an engine but a programming framework. A programming framework usually consists of two major components - Code Structure Guidelines + APIs

So only restriction on a Java developer is to follow Spring Batch program structure guidelines and usage of Spring Batch APIs is optional.Though the modeling is Read -> Process -> Write, but a Java developer is free to write any kind of logic that he or she wishes to write in these components - only thoughts can limit as what a Java developer could write in these components.Further on, one artifact can be integrated with another artifact.

So I reiterate again that Spring Batch is a programming framework & not an engine or pre configured software like Hadoop so that comparison is like apple to oranges.

[See this - Spring Tips: Spring Batch and Apache Kafka](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/15/spring-tips-spring-batch-and-apache-kafka)

As I have already said, a Java developer can develop any kind of program by being only in program structure limitations but logic being written has no bounds!

Saying one more time - Spring Batch is not an ETL tool like Informatica or Pentaho but a programming framework using Java and Spring. A developer can be as creative as he or she wants to be.

I had developed a real time data matching job that needed free text search capabilities using Apache Lucene by fitting in my programming into Spring Batch model.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch (SB) gives us all three - E, T and L.

However, we have to decide whether or not use SB. Its again a quantitative decision whether if an individual/team really needs to learn it, if they dont know it. Need to evaluate ROI (Return on Investment). If its just E or T or L only, there might be another simpler solutions.

If we talk about Java only, AND either of these three, SB is not required. But again, when it comes to simplicity (if you know SB), scalability, monitoring, Transaction Managed Parallel Processing - all these come hand-in-hand with SB out of the box.